# Badge not being awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Today I noticed something weird. My profile page said I earned this badge.

[image: awarded badge]

But I didn't got a notification in the `recent achievements` tab that I earned the badge. Also when I look at my earned badges it's not there.

[image: not awarded]

It's not like it's a big deal. But I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: @fedorqui that may explain the notification. But not why it isn't awarded.

Comment: @fedorqui true :) thanks for that link!

Comment: @fedorqui I just received it and it did give me a notification ;)

Comment: Cross-site dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253638/badge-apparently-awarded-but-not-showing.

Comment: @RetoKoradi was already solved...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The profile page tracking tells you when you have become eligible for the badge.

The actual awarding happens on a schedule, so the profile page might tell you that you have gotten through all the criteria, even though the badge has not been awarded yet.

We are still working on making it happen at the same time.

Comment: That explains most of it I think :) thanks!

Comment: I've seen this with a numpy-tag badge, I had 367 (waay off 400) and it claimed I was awarded the badge. It then changed it's mind and put back numpy to the "next-up". I should've taken a screenshot and reported...