# Incorrect badge counts for users recently awarded the Census badge

Tags: bug, badges

I was recently awarded the [new silver census badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge) and noticed something strange about it: It seems I – and also the last two batches of users rewarded with the badge, 7 and 9 hours ago respectively – have now an incorrect badge count.

I get results like the following for [different users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) and on different machines.

[image: Incorrect badge count]

Was anything changed recently or is this *working as intended* (WAI) and badge counts will be updated later?

I cannot remember experiencing such a significant delay in getting a badge and it being reflected in the badge count before.

**Update 2017-02-01:**
A day has passed and the badge counts for the user group mentioned are up-to-date again. I am still interested in an explanation though.

This is **not a duplicate** of [Badge not being awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292033/badge-not-being-awarded)  as their scenario is getting a notification and not (yet) having their profile show the badge awarded **at all**. In the case I explained here, the badge lists correctly as being awarded but the count is not accurate anymore.

<sup>(Please check the screenshot. The Census badge is there, yet the count of silver badges shows as "—" and the total is incorrect as well.)</sup>

Comment: NO WAI this is WAI. (What does WAI mean?)

Comment: WAI... NO WAI... makes me think of Wayne's World...

Comment: Badge counts are relatively tangential compared to other information about users, so they're likely to be cached for reasons of performance... [I think I know what to blame.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Comment: Cross-site dupe : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253638/badge-apparently-awarded-but-not-showing and possible duplicate of [Badge not being awarded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292033/badge-not-being-awarded)